# BLE with no Smartphone

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

Has anyone worked with BLE applications where there is no smartphone (or app) involved with very little ability for computing power?  I am formulating something around asset tracking where the use of a smartphone would not be possible and minimal computing power would exist.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting concept. But could you be more descriptive on what exactly are you trying to implement in terms of computing power?

I suppose you could try my opinions below, (Apologies for anyone who disagrees, feel free to add things here)

--> Without a smart phone can be done, if the BLE module can write some serial data to a wifi module on the same board. So you will simply program the wifi module with your wifi name and password so it can transmit logs from ble to the web and with that you could use https://thingspeak.com/ or similar IoT cloud based services to analyze your raw data to a meaningful graphical version.

--> Little ability for computing power?, Well if you want to bypass all the UI that does the processing for your raw data, the programming part will be quite complex. There are several ways to handle data BLE data, if the BLE is capable of acting as a Central and Peripheral role at the same time, you could possibly create a network of BLE modules talking to each other and use the raw data to suit your application needs.

Hope this helps.

P.s I have tried both the above methods as part of testing and they both work.

Comment: the idea would be related to asset management.  You have an asset that as it approaches a BLE device, it could trigger something like an electronic brake.  Geofencing is not the best solution for this idea so I was looking at BLE as an option.  Wifi could be an issue based on availabity.  The thought would be a device that reads BLE power levels and when the power level reaches a certain point, it would trigger a relay that would trigger the electronic brake.  THanks for your advice!

Comment: I think its a very simple approach then, you could potentially use an Arduino M0 or similar board and have some OMRON G6DN-1A (5VDC) software switched high speed relays. so simply monitor the RSSI level of the ble and write a simple code in the Arduino to turn on relays based on this.I hope this helps in your application.